# Regularity of a shrunken domain

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, euclidean-domain

I am encountering a geometrical question that intuitively seems obvious but I have a lack of argument to prove or disprove it in a rigorous manner.

Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^d$ be an open bounded (may be connected just to make it simpler)

For $\delta>0$ small enough we define the shrunken version of $\Omega$ as by 
$$\Omega_\delta= \{x\in \Omega~: \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)>\delta\}$$

Basically, for $\delta$ small enough, $\Omega$ and $\Omega_\delta$ have a similar shape. For instance if $\Omega= B(0,1)$ is the unit ball then, $\Omega_\delta=B(0,\delta) =\delta B(0,1)$ is the ball centered at 0 with radius $\delta$.

> **Definition** An open set $\Omega$ is said to satisfy the **Volum Density Condition(VDC)** if there exists a constant $\kappa>0$ such that for all $x\in \partial \Omega$ and $r\in (0,1)$
>   $$|\Omega\cap B(x,r)|\geq \kappa r^d.$$

An open set $\Omega$ is said to be of class $C^k$ if for every $x\in \partial \Omega$ there exists $r>0$ and a mapping $\gamma: \Bbb R^{d-1}\to\Bbb R$ such that

$$ \Omega\cap B(x,r)= \{x=(x',x_d)\in B(x,r)~: x_d>\gamma(x')\}$$

> A natural question would be: Does $\Omega_\delta$ inherit the regularity properties of $\Omega$? Precisely,
>
> 1)If $\Omega$ is $C^k$ do we have that $\Omega_\delta$ is also $C^k$?

2) If $\Omega$ satisfies the **Volum Density Condition(VDC)** does $\Omega_\delta$ also satisfies the  **Volum Density Condition(VDC)**?

Comment: Question 1 has a clear answer: yes if $k \geqslant 2$ and $\delta > 0$ is small enough. This is given in most textbooks on PDE's, I suppose, I can search for an exact reference if you like. However, if $\delta > 0$ is too large, then smoothness of $\Omega_\delta$ may deteriorate: consider, say, a unit ball and $\delta = 1$. Also, if $k = 1$, then $\Omega_\delta$ may become highly irregular even when $\delta > 0$ is small. An example: $\Omega$ a region above the graph of $y = |x| / \log(1/|x|)$ near $x = 0$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  Please  I would like to see does reference. Do you have an idea about what could happen with VDC condition? I technically like that condition very much.

Comment: Of course, large $\delta $ are not interesting at all.

Comment: In the example of Mateusz Kwasnicki, the "highly irregular" means "having an outward cusp", and such things do not satisfy VDC (while $C^1$ domains to, of course).

Comment: @GuyFsone: Section 14.6 in Gilbarg and Trudinger has what you need.

Comment: you might want to google 'tubular domains'... i thinkthat is the name of this type of domain (and as mentioned earlier... some pde people look at these things).    Also lots of people play arouind with the distannce function... i believe its as smooth as the boundary accept at the ''ridge''  (ie.  the ''center'' of the set)... also i recall the level sets of $ \delta$  satisfy something like $ \Delta \delta = K(x)$ where $K$ is some sort of curvature associated to the level set (maybe the mean curvature)...

Comment: i quicky googled and saw this (but i know there is tons of notes about this stuff)  https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-642-96379-7%2F1.pdf

Comment: okay; i;m an idiot... i thought it was $ \delta(x)=dist(x,\partial \Omega) <\epsilon$  not greater than... omit my comments

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki The subject treated in Gilbard and Trudinger is a different one. It mostly talks about the smoothness of the distance function on a dilated version of $\Omega$.

Comment: @GuyFsone: If $d(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$ is, say, $C^k$, then the level sets $\{d(x) = \delta\} = \partial \Omega_\delta$ are $C^k$, too (because $\nabla d \ne 0$).